# Is there a pattern for choosing one of a set of options at random when their selection criteria are equal?

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, conditions, control-structures

I want to choose between several options, and if the criteria I'm using for selection happen to be equal, I want one at random (reasonably so, so it's equal-chance each time, rather than arbitrary). This is easily done with nested ifs, but it gets pretty ugly and ends up duplicating code.

A simplified example case, in case that's not clear.

```
extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    let a = 5;
    let b = 5;

    if a > b {
        println!("Do the thing where a is bigger");
    } else if b < a {
        println!("Do the thing where b is bigger");
    } else { 
        if rand::random::<bool>() {
            // I don't want to duplicate the code here!
            println!("Do the thing where a is bigger");
        } else {
            // Or here!
            println!("Do the thing where b is bigger");
        }
    }

}
```

([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/))

Is there a better way to do this which doesn't require duplicating code? In this simplified example I'm only choosing between two possibilities, but it could actually be a longer list. (What about acting based on the highest of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, where it's possible that there's a two, three, or four-way tie?)

I happen to be learning Rust so if there's any clever language features that'd be cool, but I'm also interested in the general case if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A first general practice is to reduce duplication using functional decomposition.  This means decomposing a complex function into simpler, potentially reusable parts. Your code would then duplicate only the function calls:

```
fn do_a() {
    println!("Do the thing where a is bigger");
}
fn do_b() {
    println!("Do the thing where b is bigger");
}
fn main() {
    ...

    if a > b {
        do_a();
    } else if b < a {
        do_b();
    } else { 
        if rand::random::<bool>() {
            do_a();
        } else {
            do_b();
        }
    }
}
```

A more effective way is to refactor the code, **[consolidating the conditional expressions](https://refactoring.guru/consolidate-conditional-expression)**;  I don't know Rust, so excuse any language errors, but it would be something like:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 5;
    let b = 5;

    let agb = if a==b { rand::random::<bool>() } else { a>b };
    if agb {
        do_a();
    } else {
        do_b();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! "Consolidating the conditional expressions" is _exactly_ what I was looking for.